# Referencing value in Ruby hash in .erb file. How do I get quotes and square brackets not to display when outputs to straight html in browser?

Tags: ruby, erb

my code in index.html.erb file is posted below. When I tested in a regular ruby file, I did not see any quotes/brackets in output. However, when I use same code in erb file I see quotes and square brackets displayed around each value when viewed in browser. Is there any way to get around this?

```
---
title: Coast Guard Quiz
---

<%

seaman_recruit = {

    img: "<img src = 'images/USCG_SR.png'>",
    name: "Seaman Recruit",
    en_class: "Seaman",
    abbr: "SR",
}

seaman_apprentice = {
    img: "<img src = 'images/USCG_SA.png'>",
    name: "Seaman Apprentice",
    en_class: "Seaman",
    abbr: "SA",
}

seaman = {
    img:  "<img src = 'images/USCG_SM.png'>",
    name: "Seaman",
    en_class: "Seaman",
    abbr: "SN",
}

ranks = [seaman_recruit, seaman_apprentice, seaman]

ranks.shuffle!

current_rank = ranks.shuffle!.first

%>

<p><%= current_rank.values_at(:img) %></p>
<p class="bld"><%= current_rank.values_at(:name) %></p>
<p><%= current_rank.values_at(:en_class) %></p>
<p><%= current_rank.values_at(:abbr) %></p>
<p><%= current_rank.values_at(:title) %></p>
<p><%= current_rank.values_at(:paygrade) %></p>
```

**For example, I see this:**

["(actual image)"]

["Seaman"]

["Seaman"]

["SN"]

["Seaman (last name)"]

["E3"]

**And I want to see this:**

(actual image)

Seaman

Seaman

SN

Seaman (last name)

E3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.values_at` always returns an array. It will optionally accept multiple arguments and return the corresponding values from the hash. Since you're only giving a single argument, you get an array with one member.

You just want a standard lookup, either using bracket notation (`current_rank[:title]`, etc) or `fetch` (`current_rank.fetch(:title)`). Fetch has the added option of defining a default value to prevent errors when the provided key is not present in the hash: `current_rank.fetch(:key) { 'default value' }`.

ERB is generally not the appropriate place to define data or behavior. Assuming you're using standalone erb templates (not backed by Rails or Sinatra), I would suggest a better option would be to define your templates separate from your ruby code, either in individual files or as strings in a standard ruby file. You can take a look at the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) for some examples.

Comment: Awesome! Both standard loopup with bracket notation (current_rank[:title], etc) and fetch method worked to eliminate the extra unneeded punctuation.

Comment: I am using Middleman as framework. This is all very new to me, but I will certainly read over erb documentation and learn more about defining templates separate from ruby code. Big thanks for your help, Zach!!